# Parsing parameters to batch file by using vb script

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have a code by which i a parsing the address to the batchscript,and it is working fine but the issue is if my path is like `C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\example` then .bat file reads only upto `C:\Documents` can any one tell me what should be the issue. here is my code

Vb Script code

```
variable1="C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\example"
objWshell.run "batchfile.bat "& variable1
```

Batch script code

```
set SOURCE=%1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use literal quotes.

```
variable1="""C:\Documents and Settings\himanshu.jain\Desktop\example"""
```

Double double quotes translates to a literal double quote.